# using predict() with a continuous by continuous interaction

Tags: r, ggplot2, predict, lme4

I have a mixed model with a interaction of two continuous variables. I understand how to use predict() for a continuous by categorical interaction, but can't find any information on how to use predict() to generate graphs of continuous by continuous interactions. So far I have:

```
#the data

mydata<-structure(list(Week = c(3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), X2 = c(20.8, 21.4, 22.2, 21.9, 21, 21.8, 
16.6, 15.6, 21.9, 19.8, 17.5, 12.5, 20.1, 20.5, 21.7, 22.3), 
    X1 = c(78L, 90L, 81L, 44L, 9L, 35L, 99L, 17L, 1L, 7L, 23L, 
    14L, 9L, 77L, 84L, 1L), Y = c(14.97469781, 19.88267242, 15.59780954, 
    9.633809968, 15.12038794, 10.43636012, 10.7436911, 16.71840387, 
    12.43274774, 10.90741585, 8.79514591, 14.1932374, 8.776376951, 
    9.995133069, 12.38314719, 9.611533444)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))


#assigning 'Week' as a factor

mydata$Week<-as.factor(mydata$Week)

#the model 

model1<-glmer(Y~X1*X2+(1|Week),data=mydata, family=Gamma(link='log'))

NEWDATA <-
  expand.grid(
    X1 = seq(1, 99, length = 100),
    X2 = seq(12.5, 22.3, length = 100),
    Week = levels(mydata$Week)
  )



PREDMASS <-
  predict(model1,
          newdata = NEWDATA,
          re.form =  ~ (1 | Week))

PREDSFRAME <- cbind(NEWDATA, PREDMASS)
head(PREDSFRAME)
```

If the interaction were between a continuous and a categorical variable, I would then use the code below, but this doesn't work:

```
ggplot(PREDSFRAME, aes(x = X1, y = PREDMASS)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = mydata,
             facet_grid(. ~ X2) +
             aes(y = Y),
             alpha = 0.3)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: A "continuous by continuous interaction" is a 2-D surface; I don't think this is the right way to fit such a model. Consider asking on stats.SE for the best way of fitting a general prediction surface in the context of mixed modelling

Comment: The methods the OP used is a really common way to fit interactions between two continuous predictor variables in my field. What do you think is wrong with fitting it this way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually want the `facet_grid` outside the `geom_point()` function. If you run it that way you won't get an error.

```
ggplot(PREDSFRAME, aes(x = X1, y = PREDMASS)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = mydata,
               aes(y = Y),
             alpha = 0.3)+
  facet_grid(. ~ X2)
```

But what you get is a grid of plots for every value of X2 (because it is continuous), which is also not what you want.

What you need to do is specify some X2 values that you would create different plots (or regression lines of), since I am assuming (perhaps incorrectly) that you don't want to plot every possible combination (which is a 2D plane, as @HongOoi suggests).

I know you ask for a solution using `predict`, which perhaps you can solve with the above information, but I offer this "pre-made" solution from `sjPlot` that I find quick and helpful:

```
library(sjPlot)
plot_model(model1, type="pred",terms=c("X1","X2"))
```

[image]